# Garageband pan won't stay put

Tags: music, garageband, recording

I am trying to record and play back tracks on GarageBand and the pan feature on the tracks keep turning fully right or left without prompting. I re-set them and the same problem arises. So far this has been happening on midi tracks. How do you set the pan equally in the middle so it stays put?

Comment: If it always changes at the same point in the track, it's probably because either automation or actual MIDI Pan data is recorded in the track at that point. MIDI Pan is control 10 [cc10]. If Garage Band has a 'list' editor where you can see all the data, that's where to look. [Centre is value 64, but if you remove all hard data it will then follow the channel panner.]

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Turn off the controller on the midi track. It will disable any controller for that track, but if that's OK, this might work
1. track editor (the scissor icon)
2. track edit tool (the line with dots on it
3. Push off the button right below the word "controller"
4. wish for luck